# modify REQUEST_URI in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want server side script to see modified uri instead of the uri that was typed in browser.

Just like in the following example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)abcdef$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/ [L]
```

But the server side script still sees abcdef

Is it possible to modify REQUEST_URI literally?

Comment: I assume you are talking about php's `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` here. You could use the [P] flag for this.

Answer (score 0):

use [R] instead of [L]. this is just some text.